# What is the preferred way to upload files using gWidgetsWWW?

Tags: r, gwidgets

`gWidgetsWWW` manual indicates that the `gfilebrowse` widget is written only for local installs.

In my local prototype with `gWidgets` I was using a technique described [here](http://4dpiecharts.com/2010/10/06/creating-guis-in-r-with-gwidgets/), but as I am trying to build an app that sits on a web server, then what would be the best way to select and upload a file to the server (using `gWidgetsWWW`) for further processing?

Answer (score 0):

In `gWidgetsWWW2` the example for `gfile` shows how this can be done. (https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgetsWWW2) Serving remotely is best done through Rook, despite the scalability issue. I have some ideas on how to improve this, but they aren't more than a proof of concept right now.